# What would be the most efficient way of globally changing a color inside a react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What would be the most efficient way of globally changing the color of the contents of the following TableCell react component to the color, green?

```
class TableCell extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <SU_Table.Cell {...newProps}>
          {this.props.children}
        </SU_Table.Cell>
      );
    }
```

Would something like this work best?

```
class TableCell extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <SU_Table.Cell {{color: 'green', ...newProps}}>
          {this.props.children}
        </SU_Table.Cell>
      );
    }
```

Comment: 'most efficient’ in terms of what? Memory use? Keystrokes requires? Time to implement? Something else?

Comment: In terms of best working practice?

Comment: The example for React Context is pretty much this use case: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#when-to-use-context

Comment: Pudding pictures of code makes no sense; it's more tedious/difficult for you to get a picture instead of copying the text, it's more tedious to post a link to that image instead of pasting the text in your question, it's more difficult fur is to help you by posting a working example since we've got to transcribe an image, instead of copying & pasting... So why would you post an image of code?

Comment: Globally, or just in the respective component?

Comment: Globally would be ideal?

Answer (score 1):

The way I would generally go about it would be to add a conditional style prop to it, depending on whether or not the element is passed a color:

```
<SU_Table.Cell {...props} style={this.props.color ? {color: this.props.color} : {color: defaultColor}}>
  {this.props.children}
<SU_Table.Cell />
```

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for though, let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks for your help! So how would the code you wrote change if I wanted to make it green?